# stale file handle in unix sed command

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I am getting stale file handle error in my shell script. This is basically coming from `sed` command:

```
sed 's/|~|/temp_delim/g' ${file} | sed 's/|/ /g'| sed 's/temp_delim/|/g' > file1
```

**Error:**

```
sed: couldn't write 172 items to stdout: Stale file handle
```

Note: Size of `${file}` is around 2GB.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when your filesystem where you are writing STDOUT to, is out of space or out of inode. What is the output of df -h and df -i?

Comment: @ R-Dit  df -h  /filesystem  @ 6% and df -i /filesystem @ 6%. and  df -k /tmp  Use% @ 2% I have enough space. Is there something wrong with command then?

Comment: check also df -k /tmp and please post where the file1 is located

Comment: /home/syadav/files/srcfiles/${file} and          /home/syadav/files/targetfiles/file1

Comment: I strongly belive that this is related to the space so check the mount point of /home/ with df -h /home/syadav

Answer (score 0):

Try without pipe and with unambigous `|`

```
sed 's/[|]~[|]/temp_delim/g
     s/[|]/ /g
     s/temp_delim/|/g
     ' ${file} > file1
```

With a bit of optmization for runtime

```
sed '/[|]~[|] !{
        s/[|]/ /g
        b
        }
     s//temp_delim/g
     s/[|]/ /g
     s/temp_delim/|/g
     ' ${file} > file1
```

- both are posix compliant, with GNU sed you can replace newline by `;` for a oneliner
- It is assumed that there is no `temp_delim` string inside the file